# Build latest freetype with emscripten

Tags: clang, webassembly, emscripten

Can anyone capable help me build the [latest](https://sourceforge.net/projects/freetype/files/freetype2/2.10.1/) Freetype with emscripten? The one in the ports repository is really old.
I tried building the latest release myself but I kept getting the following error when I run `emmake make`

```
freetype/objs/apinames: Permission denied
freetype/objs/ftexport.sym] Error 1
```

I don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3):

I got help from the WebAssembly discord community and it turns out the autotools build system of freetype is broken, but turns out they also have cmake build system which turns out works fine with emscripten

Use the following steps

```
mkdir build

cd build

emcmake cmake ..

emmake make

emmake make install
```